# Configuration of the Windows Explorer Layout keyboard shortcuts

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

**Configuration of the Windows Explorer Layout keyboard shortcuts**

How can you control the keyboard shortcuts for the Explorer Layout?

On my old PC, the shortcuts were of the format ... <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>number</kbd>, e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> changes the Layout to **"List"**, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> changes it to **"Extra Large Icons"**, etc.

Just got a new PC, and the shortcuts are now of the format ... <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>number</kbd>

The main difference between the PC's is my old one was Windows 10, then updated to Windows 11, whereas the new one is straight Windows 11

Comment: There seems to be always leftovers from OS upgrades.  Do a Windows 11 Repair Install of the upgraded machine and Keep Everything (non invasive).  Use the Microsoft Media Creation Link for this.  This may reset keyboard shortcuts.